# How long and far can you kite a mob?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How long will a mob chase you after you enter combat with it? How far will it chase you? Will attacking the mob during chase completely reset the time / distance that it will chase you?

Comment: The distance at which a mob leashes varies wildly by mob and zone. It's not a fixed value. There are techniques and tricks that will let you kite a mob further away, and many mobs will always leash if you bring them across a boundary at the edge of 'their' area.

Comment: @LessPop Would you consider region-bound mobs to be the exception or the rule?

Comment: I think you'd also have to factor in damage done to the mob and the mobs health pools. Because kiting generally involves some form of damage, minus the lock & mage who both have ranged snares. This would obviously limit how far you can kite a mob.

Comment: As a Mage, I can Polymorph an enemy to heal it if it's getting low. :)

Comment: In TBC expansion, you could kite for inifity as a paladin. The cooldown, silly low damage and combat refreshness from Level 1 Consecration let you kite things for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, as has been pointed out, varies wildly, but generally, in the overworld, mobs can be kited for any amount of *time*, but if you move too far from where you entered combat, they'll snap back.

In dungeons, mobs will generally follow you until you or they die, although there are exceptions (besides the obvious, such as bosses).

Of course, occasionally strange cases have appeared, and mobs have been known to be kited from the Blasted Lands to Stormwind…

Comment: Or Fel Reavers from HP to Shattrah city or the hunter epic bow/staff quest from Vanilla to kill a demon, which had the hunter kiting for a long time.